# CentOS 7 Encrypt a PDF

Tags: centos, terminal, encryption, pdf

I've recently upgraded our server from CentOS 6 to CentOS 7 and I am having issues getting pdf encryption working on it.

On CentOS 6 I installed libgcj and then the pdftk package. I could then encrypt pdfs using

```
/usr/sbin/pdftk pdfName.pdf output pdfEncrypted.pdf owner_pw 123456 user_pw 123654
```

I know I cannot install pdftk on CentOS 7 because it does not support libgcj but is there an alternate way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Alternative:** use `qpdf`. It's on CentOS 7 base system.

```
# yum install qpdf
$ qpdf --encrypt user-password owner-password 40 -- file1.pdf file2.pdf
```

This will take file1.pdf as input, assign user and owner passwords, a key length of 40(valid values are 40, 128, or 256) and export the encrypted data to file2.pdf

To "unlock" pdf files:

```
$ qpdf --decrypt --password=password locked.pdf unlocked.pdf
```

You can find [here](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.encryption-options) more qpdf encrypt options

**Second Alternative:** There is the possibility to use any general purpouse file encryption tool. You can find a well explained document about some of them [here](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-password-protect-files-with-encryption/).